# Django, how to use render_to_response with many templates

Tags: python, django, templates

Hello i am newbie in Django, started to learn it today and i have problem with template inheritance
i have such function in my view:

```
def show(request, id=1):

return render_to_response('template1.html', {
    'name': name,
    'model1': Model1.objects.get(id=id),
    'model2': Model2.objects.get(id=id).model1,
})
```

And i have 3 different templates, main.html with such code:

```
<body>
{% block block1 %}
{% endblock %}
{% block block2 %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and two more tempaltes that contains code like that:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block block1 %}
    <h2>{{ var }}</h2>
    <pre>{{ var }}</pre>
{% endblock %}
```

second one is very similar so i wont show it, problem is: i dont know which one to put in render_to_response function.
if i put main.html:

```
 return render_to_response('main.html', {
```

it doesn't load any templates, but content from main.html appears well, i can just see empty space on page
if i put template1:

```
return render_to_response('template1.html', {
```

It load only content from main and from template1.html but i need content from template2.html

if i put template2.html to function it only shows content from main.html and from template2.html but no content from template1.html
Please help me how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1)** Try using the `{% include %}` tag.

---

`main.html`

```
<head> ... </head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

---

`template1.html`

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block content %}
     <h1>Hello world</h1>
     {% include "nested_template2.html" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

---

`nested_template2.html`

```
<p>The world is smaller than you think.</p>
```

---

In your view/controller:

```
return render_to_response('template1.html', {
```

---

**Option 2)** Chain `{% extends ... %}` tags as deep as you want. I frquently use this structure:

```
templates/
----base.html
----projects/
    ----_.html
    ----detail.html
    ----list.html
```

The `base.html` is the master layout. The `folder/_.html` is specific to a "stage" (more modular content).

---

`base.html`

```
<head> ... </head>
<body>
{% block stage_content %}
{% endblock stage_content %}
```

---

`projects/_.html`

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block stage_content %}
     <h1>Project Stage</h1>
     {% block page_content %}
     {% endblock page_content %}
{% endblock stage_content %}
```

---

`projects/list.html`

```
{% extends "projects/_.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
   {% for project in projects %}
       <li>{{ project.name }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock page_content %}
```

---

`projects/detail.html`

```
{% extends "projects/_.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
   Viewing project {{ project.name }}
{% endblock page_content %}
```

---

In your view/controller:

```
return render_to_response('projects/detail.html', {
```

Comment: I dont like that, i need to include one template to another one, are you sure there is no simplier solution?

Comment: I added another option.

Comment: thank you very much for you ideas i will mark answer as solution later, maybe i will get more options so i will wait.